# In Preview is there a way to view two pages one below the other

Tags: macos, osx-lion, osx-mountain-lion

In `Preview`, in the Two-Pages View (Cmd-3 or View > Two-Pages), is there a way to view two pages one *below* the other?

This is useful especially when the pages are in landscape mode e.g. slides.

The default two-page view shows pages next to one another.

Answer (score 1):

Another work around is to insert (or copy) a blank page in front of the 1st page. That way a 2-page document becomes a 3-page one and the page 2 and 3 will after hitting Command-3 be displayed side-by-side.
Edit -> Insert -> Blank Page.
Or just copy/paste one of the existing pages in the sidebar - grab the thumbnail with the alt key - drop to paste.
Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try right clicking in your pdf and selecting "[Two Pages Continuous](https://reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/osw8te/after_a_decade_of_using_mac_i_only_now_realize/)"

Answer (score 0):

By default the PDF will show images one on top of the other (vertically). If you shrink the window down enough you will see two pages.

Comment: I meant in the two-page view (Cmd-3 or View > Two-Pages).

Comment: Ah, I get it. No, there is no way (not that I can find anyway). But there is a work around: "print" and set layout to 2 pages per page - then save as PDF. Open that PDF and set to Continuous Scroll (Command+1).

Not ideal - but I am open to other options.

Adobe Reader does do this (View > Page Display > Two-Page Scrolling)